# try: and expect: string error handling in python

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

Currently learning about try and except and trying out to catch errors with dividing to numbers

This is my code:

```
def divide(a, b): 
    try:
        return a/b
    except ZeroDivisionError: 
        return "dividing by zero not possible "
    except TypeError:
        return "a and b must both be integers"
    except NameError:
        return "a and b must both be integers"


print(divide(2,a))
```

but for some reason it does not catch the TypeError and NameError when I make the second value ' a '
and returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Python/Learning-Python/Section 18/Section_18_errors.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(divide(2,a))
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

My try and expect catches the NameError right? Shouldnt it return "a and b must both be integers"

Comment: It's never calling `divide` because it fails when it tries to evaluate the arguments.  You need to assign a value to `a` before you can pass it as a function argument.

Comment: Your function doesn't get entered because the exception is thrown by the line `print(divide(2,a))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're calling it, `divide(2,a)` the interpreter is looking for the variable `a` to have a value. Since you haven't assigned a value to `a`, it throws the NameError of not being defined. As other comments and answers have pointed out, you have to make `a` a character instead of a variable, which you can do by assigning a value to `a`, as in `a = 'a'`, or just pass it as a string itself (i.e. `divide(2,'a')`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try passing a character instead of integer, try: `print(divide(2,"a"))`.

Passing `a` without defining it before will cause a failure during the evaluation of your code and not during runtime and that's why catching `NameError` won't help here.